# Вывод данных из JSON на страницу

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, couchdb

Возможно, заголовок немного неправильный, я не знаю что написать.
Знакомлюсь с CouchDB, документации на русском крайне мало, сижу потихоньку разбираю английские мануалы.

Я создал базу данных и теперь хочу вытащить из нее данные, в документации сказано, что это нужно делать GET запросом, окей.

JSON строка:

```html
{"_id":"897d2c6aabd1625781acded73300184f","_rev":"3-d7403362dfb26c3a1d7a89af19674664","name":"Никита","age":21,"status":1,"phone":[{"work":"23224"},{"home":"4244242"}]}
```

```html
$.ajax({
   dataType: "jsonp",
   url: "http://localhost:5984/users/897d2c6aabd1625781acded73300184f",
   crossDomain: true,
   success: console.log("succes")
 });
```

P.S. jsonp, а не просто json, я указал чтобы избежать ошибки доступа (это решение нашел тут, на стаке).

А что делать дальше я так и не пойму. Как мне вывести эти данные? Знаю что вернется строка, но каким образом и куда она вернется?  Заранее спасибо.

Comment: какой сервер посылает запросы в базу?

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich мой компьютер

Comment: база в браузере?

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich не совсем понимаю о чем ты

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данные будут переданны в `success`, но в текущем варианте вы их не уидите.

Вы неверно используете `success`.

```
$.ajax({
      dataType: "jsonp",
      url: "http://localhost:5984/users/897d2c6aabd1625781acded73300184f",
      crossDomain: true,
      success: console.log("succes")
    });
```

Выведет `success` ещё до того как выполнится запрос (даже до того как он начнет выполнятся).

Это произойдет из-за порядка вычисления аргуметнов функции

Браузер прочтёт вызов `$.ajax()`, затем начнёт вычислять аргументы.

```
{
  dataType: "jsonp",
  url: "http://localhost:5984/users/897d2c6aabd1625781acded73300184f",
  crossDomain: true,
  success: console.log("succes")
}
```

Браузер создаст объект, добавит в него поле `dataType`, проверит значение поля, увидит что это строка "jsonp" и выставит значение полня в 'jsonp'. Аналогично для `url` и  `crossDomain`. При проверке значения поля success он увидит что это **вызов** метода `console.log()`. Javascript вызовет метод `console.log()` с параметром "success" (который тоже будет отдельно проверен и, если нужно, вычислен), получит возвращаемое значение (в данном случае `undefined`) и присвое значение `undefined` в поле `success`.

Затем вызовет

```
$.ajax({
      dataType: "jsonp",
      url: "http://localhost:5984/users/897d2c6aabd1625781acded73300184f",
      crossDomain: true,
      success: undefined, // тоесть вы ничего не передали в success
    });
```

Для того чтобы браузер распечатал полученное значение, либо вывел "success" после того как фактически будут полченны данные нужно в метод поле `success` передать метод.

К примеру так:

```
var log = console.log.bind( console );
$.ajax({
      dataType: "json",
      url: "http://localhost:5984/users/897d2c6aabd1625781acded73300184f",
      crossDomain: true,
      success: log, // без круглых скобочек
    });
```

Данные полученные с сервера будут переданны в первом параметре.

Comment: спасибо, но выдает ошибку, которую выдавал и раньше. 897d2c6…?callback=jQuery1111076…_1469471052054&_=1469471052055:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : ошибка в самом json файле?

Comment: можно полностью ошибку?

Comment: и текст котрый приходит с сервера (можно увидеть в консоли).

Comment: http://pastenow.ru/Upload/Paste/T6RC.png это консоль

Comment: http://pastenow.ru/Upload/Paste/T6S9.png это то, что возвращается

Comment: Полагаю у вас не разрешён CORS в конфиге CouchDB. [Cдесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371774/couchdb-cross-domain-access-from-xmlhttprequest#answer-20569815) Опции конфигурации которые должны быть в конфиге.

Comment: В приведённом коде была ошибка (должно быть `console.log.bind( console)` либо `function(){console.log.apply( console, arguments) }`, после того как поправите конфиг, обновите код.

Comment: та же ошибка, функцию тоже поменял, все так же

Comment: попробуйте заменить "jsonp" на "json"